# Bluetooth penetration testing

Tags: bluetooth

I need to do some testing on boxed devices, incidentally having Bluetooth interface. I am quite sure that there are problems in the implementation, at least there must be given how the architecture has been developed.

My question is: where can I find some theory on Bluetooth attacks? I am not happy only with BlueSnarfing or BlueJacking, or anyways 'old school' attacks. Any source of info is well accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Have you taken a look at the [Ubertooth](http://ubertooth.sourceforge.net/) project?  It's a hardware platform plus a good bit of code to get you started in Bluetooth analysis.  Also, I found [Mike Ryan's Black Hat presentation](https://media.blackhat.com/us-13/us-13-Ryan-Bluetooth-Smart-The-Good-The-Bad-The-Ugly-and-The-Fix.pdf) from last year to be helpful:    (links directly to the pdf)